# PropertyGrid does not raise PropertyValueChanged event

Tags: c#, propertygrid

When user changes text or bool value in PropertyGrid I set `flagModified=true;` in event handler:

```
private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        propertyGrid1.Refresh();
        PropertyChanged(true);
    }
```

and then Save button is enabled.

I use my Editor and form (see class below) to edit one of values in Properrtygrid. It is object of my class. 
After object is changed in editor and editor closed I re-assign value of object to the new value (value = frm.m_DS;). All works fine but one moment: in this case PropertyValueChanged is not raised.
I use PropertyValueChanged event to enable my button "Save" which saves all properties to file.
How I can catch event that value is changed and enable Save button?.

```
public class DataProviderEditor : UITypeEditor
    {

        public override Object EditValue(
          ITypeDescriptorContext context,
          IServiceProvider provider,
          Object value)
        {
            if ((context != null) && (provider != null))
            {
                IWindowsFormsEditorService svc =
                  (IWindowsFormsEditorService)
                  provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

                if (svc != null)
                {
                    using (DatasourceForm frm =
                      new DatasourceForm((MyDatasource)value))
                    {
                        if (svc.ShowDialog(frm) == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            value = frm.m_DS;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
        }
```

Comment: _But when I use my editor for object then_ - what do you mean here? Can you rephrase?

Comment: It can only reliably raise the event for values that it edits itself, not for ones that it hands off to another editor.  It doesn't have the plumbing to compare values of type *object*.  There is no easy fix for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed the documentation about the event `PropertyGrid.PropertyValueChanged` is flawed. It doesn't mention that the event is raised only if the user changes the value. You can find this out if you check the [`PropertyValueChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertyvaluechangedeventargs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) documentation, which says:

> The PropertyValueChanged event occurs when the user changes the value of a property, which is specified as a GridItem, in a PropertyGrid.

What you can do is to add `PropertyValueChanged` event to the object that is browsed by `PropertyGrid`. You can code it similar to this:

```
public class BrowsedObject
{
    public event EventHandler PropertyValueChanged;

    private void OnPropertyValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler eh = PropertyValueChanged;
        if (eh != null)
            eh(sender, e);
    }

    private string someProperty;
    public new string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return someProperty; }
        set
        {
            someProperty = value;
            OnPropertyValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Each time a new value is assigned to `SomeProperty` the object will raise `PropertyValueChanged`. You can hook up to this event logic that is to enable *Save button* etc.

**Or**

Why don't you just call `PropertyChanged(true);` each time you change the object property from the code.

Comment: Thanx Dzienny. I tried INotifyPropertyChanged.  It is solution too.

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple "autoupdate" staff you can do this:

```
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = propertyGrid1.SelectedObject;
```

It's seems it worked, change is visible.