# Editing and firing PropertyValueChanged event for a List<string> in a PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to edit a `List<string>` with a PropertyGrid and it's not firing a PropertyValueChanged event when it's contents are modified.

I researched this and tried to use a custom `TypeConverter` class, but even when I get the editor to show and let me modify the values I can't get this event to fire.

I also tried using the below attribute and it pulls up the string editor, but this also doesn't fire the event on changes.

```
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
```

I also tried using a `UITypeEditor` and overriding the `EditValue` method, but this never fires when editing the values.

```
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
{
  MessageBox.Show("This never appears...");
  return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
}
```

Is there a way to edit a `List<string>` *and* fire the PropertyValueChanged event?

Comment: Did you try this:
[PropertyGrid does not raise PropertyValueChanged event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110594/propertygrid-does-not-raise-propertyvaluechanged-event

Comment: Yes, this doesn't call the event when the property is changed through the PropertyGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `BindingList<string>` instead of `List<string>` to get `PropertyValueChanged` event fired.

**Edit:**

@LarsTech pointed out that `ObservableCollection<string>` is practically used in WPF but not winforms, and you should use `BindingList<string>` instead.

In short, `BindingList` supports more interfaces and more feature than `ObservableCollection`. Here are some advantages to go with `BindingList`:

- `BindingList` implements `IBindingList<T>`, but `ObservableCollection` does not. `IBindingList` provides a whole bunch of functionality which can be used by the UI to provide a lot more things, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist) for more details
- `BindingList` implements `ICancelAddNew` that data binding mechanisms uses for cancelling the newly added item;
- `ObservableCollection` does not listen to changes in its children but only to `Insert` and `Remove` events;

Point 2 and 3 full credits to: [ObservableCollection(Of T) vs BindingList(Of T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455284/observablecollectionof-t-vs-bindinglistof-t)

Comment: In WinForms, BindingList<T> is usually used.

Comment: This ended up working for me. I subscribed to the `ListChanged` event of a `BindingList`. This event fires one more time than the number of items in the list, so I had to account for that. Not exactly what I was looking for, but this got me up and going. Thanks! edit: Also, this doesn't fire the `PropertyValueChanged`, at least not that I could tell.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by langstrom, the BindingList does doesn't fire the event PropertyValueChanged.

I used a simple and ugly workaround: I set the complete collection (it only has a few items) after adapting it:

CollectionValue=CollectionValue

(My aim was to get a red border around my custom PropertyGrid Editor for a ObservableCollection(Of String) if IDataErrorInfo provides some error for the edited property.)

Also see

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/544080 (discussion)

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/20977 (issue ticket)

Answer (score 0):

If your BindingList doesn't refresh after you modify a value with a PropertyGrid you can call yourBindingList.ResetBindings() to trigger the changes.